# many rows into a single column with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an one to many table, and if there is rows that have same reference id(Paragraph ID) I want to concatenate so LoginName value have many in same row.

This query does what I want it to do but there is a problem, It replaces first char. the STUFF function requires a replace value.

**My question:**
How can I do this without replacing first char?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
          ParagraphID
        , STUFF((
            SELECT N'|' + CAST([LoginName] AS VARCHAR(255))
            FROM [dbo].[CM_Signature] f2
            WHERE f1.ParagraphID = f2.ParagraphID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS FileNameString
    FROM [dbo].[CM_Signature] f1
```

[image]

Expected value:

```
Daniel | Emma
```

Comment: give sample data and expected output...

Comment: Looks to me like you have ripped off this query somewhere and you have no idea what is going on ;)

Comment: Your expected output is `Aniel | Emma` or `Daniel | Emma`? it's quite confusing because the sample you give do not match your description.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Daniel | Emma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          ParagraphID
        , STUFF((
            SELECT N' | ' + CAST([LoginName] AS VARCHAR(255))
            FROM [dbo].[CM_Signature] f2
            WHERE f1.ParagraphID = f2.ParagraphID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS FileNameString
FROM [dbo].[CM_Signature] f1
```

Note the `STUFF("...", 1, 1, '')` instead of `STUFF("...", 1, 2, '')`.
Because you need to replace 1 char instead of 2 (To remove the first `|`).

Output:

```
Daniel|Emma
```

Also, if you want to have spaces before and after the `|`, just use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          ParagraphID
        , STUFF((
            SELECT N' | ' + CAST([LoginName] AS VARCHAR(255))
            FROM [dbo].[CM_Signature] f2
            WHERE f1.ParagraphID = f2.ParagraphID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 3, '') AS FileNameString
FROM [dbo].[CM_Signature] f1
```

Note that this time we removed 3 chars (`STUFF("...", 1, 3, '')`).

Output:

```
Daniel | Emma
```

Answer (score 3):

You were starting your path at position 2 instead of first

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          ParagraphID
        , STUFF((
            SELECT N'|' + CAST([LoginName] AS VARCHAR(255))
            FROM [dbo].[CM_Signature] f2
            WHERE f1.ParagraphID = f2.ParagraphID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS FileNameString
    FROM [dbo].[CM_Signature] f1    SELECT DISTINCT
              ParagraphID
            , STUFF((
                SELECT N'|' + CAST([name] AS VARCHAR(255))
                FROM mytable f2
                WHERE f1.paragraphid = f2.paragraphid
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS FileNameString
        FROM mytable f1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this Code:

```
create table #test (paragraghid int,name VARCHAR(10))

insert into #test values(1929,'Daniel')
insert into #test values(1929,'Emma')
insert into #test values(1935,'Daniel')   


select distinct paragraghid,STUFF((select ' | ' + name from #test a 
Where a.paragraghid=b.paragraghid for XML PATH('')  ),1,2,'') as FilenameString
from #test b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a query as:

```
DECLARE @CM_Signature table 
(
RowId int,
ParagraphID int,
LoginName varchar(10))
Insert into @CM_Signature values
(4,1929,'  Daniel'),
(5,1929,'    Emma  '),
(6,1935,'Daniel')

SELECT DISTINCT
          ParagraphID
        , STUFF((
            SELECT N'| ' + CAST(rtrim(ltrim([LoginName])) AS VARCHAR(255))
            FROM @CM_Signature f2
            WHERE f1.ParagraphID = f2.ParagraphID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS FileNameString
    FROM @CM_Signature f1
```